# Enable Recurring payment for 2Checkout in NopCommerce 2.70

Tags: nopcommerce, 2checkout

I have a running production website from more then a year now which is based on NopCommerce 2.70 and on top of it i just changed the theme of it so that it's fit in our flavor.

As an payment i am using https://www.2checkout.com/, till this moment all of my products are for one time payment and customer are successfully able to make payment and purchase the product, but now i have few services which need to cost low and better in fit for 'pay as you go model' means recurring option of atleast monthly.

I check the source code of the plugin and i can see there are methods related to handle recurring payments. So for test i setup one test product/service (Recurring option enabled) in my production website but when i tried to purchase that product it gives me error of

No payment methods available

When i Check my payment configuration page where all payment methods are listed there also under 'Recurring support' column it shows NotSupported.
I studied from the documentation of 2Checkout website that they support recurring payments.

Please help me out, what i need to change/customize in order to enabled the recurring payments.

Regard
Vishal Gupta

Answer (score 0):

In the **IPaymentMethod** class you will need the change the **RecurringPaymentType** property to either Automatic or Manual. Which one you choose depends your payment provider.

**Automatic** will activate the payment upon an external HTTP request i.e IPN request. **Manual** will  create the first record on placed order, further payments you need to activate manually in Admin.

Comment: Hi Gusten, There is no IPaymentMethod class there is just Interface with this name under library project 'Nop.Services'. i guess this setting need to be done in the 2checkout plugin itself so that when nop-commerce loads the plugin it convey to nopcommerce that this plugin is recurring enabled. Regarding handling i guess there is already code present in plugin which do the same job.

Comment: There should be a class in your plugin that implements IPaymentMethod where this property is located. Do you have access to the source code of the plugin?